# How should I handle a conditional in Ruby where the test could result in an error?

Tags: javascript, ruby, conditional-operator, or-operator

I have a situation like this:

```rb
# self refers to an instance of a Book class
self.author = instance_of_author_class                    #returns instance
self.author.name = instance_variable_in_author_instance   #returns string

# this is an instance method of the Book class:
def author_name
    self.author ? self.author.name : nil                  #returns string or nil
end
```

This code works fine, as it first checks to see if there is an `author` set, then returns its name, or `nil` if no author is set.

However, I would love to be able to do this with a bit less code, as I find I'm often in the situation where I want to "**just return the thing if it exists**". I don't love having to test the thing before simply returning it. The `||` OR expression seems like it would work perfect.

```rb
def author_name
    self.author.name || nil
end
```

This would work great if `self.author.name` was somehow pre-initialized as `false` or `nil`, but unfortunately if the `author` isn't set to some valid instance (and that valid instance also has the `name` method defined), then I'll get:

```rb
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

And unfortunately, ruby doesn't seem to treat errors like this as `false`, it stops execution.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this goal?

(javascript stackoverflow tag added as well, because I'd welcome javascript solutions too!)

Comment: _"I'd welcome javascript solutions too"_ – how could that possibly help when you have Ruby code?

Comment: @Stefan I guess I'm referring to the general problem of "just return the thing if it exists" with nested-error-handling. I feel like that's a problem I'll continue to have, regardless of language, and I could perhaps handoff some logic to different tools if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the [safe navigation operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537) which was introduced to Ruby in 2.3:

```
def author_name
  author&.name
end
```

Note that `self` is not needed in your example.

Or when you are on Ruby on Rails then you might want to use [`delegate`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate):

```
delegate :name, to: :author, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the rapid answer! I like this solution a lot! Re: `self`, I like to include it explicitly because it kind of determines that `author` runs the `author` method (getting the instance variable `@author`). I generally worry that leaving off the `self` might imply that `author` is some local variable. In your experience, is my fear unfounded and it's better practice to leave it off?

Comment: When you have both an `author` method and an `author` local variable then calling `author` would, of course, return the variable. But if you do not have such a variable then there is no need for the `self.`

Comment: @Ben: the general wisdom is that if your scopes are so large and your code so convoluted that you cannot even keep track of what is a local variale and what is a method, then you have much bigger problems that even explicitly annotating methods will not help you with.

Comment: @Ben use a decent editor / IDE that’s capable of detecting and syntax highlighting local variables. I can highly recommended RubyMine.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks yeah, my scopes are small, i'm just early in my ruby days and trying to learn what is common practice (and the rationales for such) so i can be consistent :)